# cannot change maven local repository path

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to change the path of the local maven repository, but always when I restart intellij idea, this path is automatically reset to the value "/data/m2repository":
[image]

Was I already tried:

- changing the path direct in the file ~/.IntelliJIdea14/system/Maven/Indices/Index0/index.properties
- changing the path variable MAVEN_REPOSITORY in intellij system configuration

How can I change this path permanently? I'm using Intellij Idea 14.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. The wrong path was defined in ~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
<settings>
...
   <localRepository>/data/m2repository</localRepository> 
...
</settings>
```

I commented it out and now the value in Intellij is not longer changed.

However I think, setting the correct value in Intellij should overwrite the value in settings.xml. Intellij Idea bug?

Answer (score 1):

For IntelliJ Community Edition 2020.3, go to File | Settings | Build, Execution Deployment | Maven, and change the "Local repository:" by clicking on the Override checkbox on the right and entering the path to its left.